# Hidden Div Not Showing Properly

Tags: css, html

I'm having an issue with a hidden div showing at the very end of a coldfusion loop. When I need it to show right underneath each individual row. You can see what i'm talking about at the URL below (click on "Learn More" under any one of the 1st four fragrances, you will see that the hidden div shows underneath the Fleur D'Orange fragrance.

http://www.mefragrance.com/shop.cfm?collectionid=4

What I need is for it to show underneath the 1st row of 4 fragrances. I would also need this to show properly in mobile devices. So basically i'm looking for the hidden div to show underneath each individual fragrance, but occupy the full width of a row.

Right now I have the div after the full loop, so I understand why it shows it at the very bottom of all the products. But when I move it underneath or within the product loop, everything gets wonky and things get moved around weird.

Below is the code I've tried, which is basically putting the hidden layer underneath each div (ie under each fragrance), which is what i want. The problem is that instead of the row going 4 divs across, it puts a break after each div and you have just one column all the way down. You can see the result here:

http://www.mefragrance.com/shop_test.cfm?collectionid=4

Here is the code

```
<style>
#menu_container{
width: auto;
height: auto;
padding-left:50px;
padding-top: 20px; 
}

#menu_container div {display: none;}
</style>

<div style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 15px; ">           
    <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 25px;">
        <img src="graphics/premixed/jasmin_epice_noir_3.4.jpg" style="max-width: 250px; height: auto;">
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 5px; " class="how-it-works-grey">
        Jasmin Épice Noir
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 15px; ">                       
        <i class="fa fa-female fa-lg"></i><img src="graphics/sex_quotient_1.png"><i class="fa fa-male fa-lg"></i>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 25px;">
        <a class="greenbutton-42px-high" style="text-decoration:none; min-width: 150px; color: white; " href="shop.cfm?premixedid=4&fullcollection=1&collectionid=4">SHOP PRODUCTS <i class="icon-right-open-big" style="font-weight: 500; font-size: 18px; "></i></a>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
        <a id="show_4" class="whitebutton-42px-high" style="text-decoration:none; min-width: 150px; " href="javascript:void(0)">LEARN MORE <i class="icon-down-open-big" style="font-weight: 500; font-size: 18px; "></i></a>
    </div>                                      
</div>                  

<!-- Hidden Layer -->   
<div id="menu_container">
    <div id="menu_4" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom:20px;">               
        <p class="how-it-works-grey"><u>Jasmin Épice Noir</u></p>               
        <p style="line-height: 18px; padding-top: 0px;">An irresistible fragrance that is mysterious and intensely voluptuous. A spiced floral fragrance with a precious blend of jasmine grandiflorum absolute and rich spices. A combination of spices such as black pepper & ginger root give this fragrance a spicy mix. Includes accents of almond oil & clary sage essential oil. The fragrance is then rounded out with vanilla essential oil to let the heart notes come through and give it a rich subtle sweet scent.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Hidden Layer -->


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#nav a").click(function(){
  var id =  $(this).attr('id');
  id = id.split('_');
  $("#menu_container div").hide( "slow" ); 
  $("#menu_container #menu_"+id[1]).show( "slow" );
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: @user3285739 Could you provide what you have so far and also if possible a working copy in https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see exactly what your issue is

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may also benefit from reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the other [Stack Overflow help articles on "Asking"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @murday1983 I've added additional code as to what I've tried. Only issue is the line break that it's doing after each fragrance div, which then creates just one column rows.

Comment: @user3285739 I presume that you are also using `JQuery`/`JavaScript` to hide/show your hidden `DIV`. Could you provide everything you are using `JQuery`/`JavaScript` & any `CSS` so we can get a complete picture

Comment: @murday1983 I've posted the additional code, yes I'm using jquery 1.9.1

Comment: the issue is that the hidden div creates a line break(thus creating a one column row), is there a way to prevent the hidden div from causing that line break?

Comment: can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this only with html and css.

You have to create a div under each 4 boxes(rows) and use javascript to show each box content into below div.